# Find the maximum value of expression $Q=\dfrac{a}{ad+bc}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Can you help me find the maximum value of
$Q= \dfrac{a}{ad+bc}$

$a^2+b^2=1, c^2+d^2=4, ac-bd=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $$\begin{align} (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2& \implies 4 = 0+(ad+bc)^2\\ \\
& \implies ad+bc=\pm 2\implies |Q| \le \dfrac{|a|}{2}\le \dfrac{1}{2}\\ \\ &\implies Q_\text{max} = \dfrac{1}{2}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$a^2+b^2=1\implies$$
$$a=\cos(u)\;,\;b=\sin(u)$$

$$c^2+d^2=4\implies$$
$$c=2\cos(v)\;,\; d=2\sin(v)$$

$$ac=bd\implies $$
$$2\cos(u)\cos(v)=2\sin(u)\sin(v)$$
$$\implies \cos(u+v)=0$$
$$\implies u+v=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$

So
$$\frac{a}{ad+bc}=$$
$$\frac{\cos(u)}{2\sin(u+v)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos(u)}{\pm 2}$$

the max is $\frac 12$.